# how to break connection pull in pgsql?

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_() RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$ 
declare
    foo int; 
BEGIN

FOR i IN 1..50 LOOP         
    foo = i;
    RAISE NOTICE 'combination_array(%)', foo ;
    UPDATE table_1 set r_id = foo WHERE id = (select id from table_1 where r_id is null order by id limit 1); 
END LOOP;

END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;

SELECT add_();
```

after this execution when ever i execute

```
UPDATE table_1 
   set r_id = foo 
WHERE id = (select id from table_1 where r_id is null order by id limit 1); 

END LOOP;
```

its going to be busy any one tell me how to clear the pull in pgsql

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "clear the pull".

Comment: when i execute the query after the script its going to be busy because database connection is busy. will you guide me how to close the connection?

Comment: How about pressing Ctrl+C on the keyboard?

Comment: Maybe the question is how to quit psql while the query is still running to completion in background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's return all connection with ids

```
SELECT * from pg_stat_activity;
```

You can kill the specific connection by procpid though following  query.

```
select pg_terminate_backend(procpid)
    from pg_stat_activity
    where datname = 'database-name'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send signal to this busy connected backend process.

To cancel a running query, send the SIGINT signal to the process running that command. To terminate a backend process cleanly, send SIGTERM to that process.

for exp :

```
pg93@db-172-16-3-150-> psql
psql (9.3.3)
Type "help" for help.
digoal=# select pg_sleep(1000000);
-- find the pid
-- ps -ewf|grep postgres
pg93     24872 23190  0 00:11 ?        00:00:00 postgres: postgres digoal [local] SELECT

-- send signal
pg93@db-172-16-3-150-> kill -s SIGINT 24872
-- then we see that feedback from psql.
ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
```

Comment: It may be easier to use `pg_cancel_backend(pid int)` or `pg_terminate_backend(pid int)` to cancell query and `pg_stat_activity` view to get the `pid`.

Comment: YES, but when there is no more connect for dba? you shold kill it use signal.